# Parsing Phone Number without the use of split

Tags: java

I am attempting to write a JAVA program for school. It requires that we use a provided class, refrain from the use of split, and parse a phone number separated by `:` between the different parts.

```
    package aaronjonesprog1;


public class AaronJonesProg1 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        AJDissector phone = new AJDissector("1:919:882:5000");
        System.out.println(phone.getPhoneNumber());
        System.out.println(phone.getPhoneNumber(4));
        System.out.println(phone.getPhoneNumber(1));
        System.out.println(phone.getPhoneNumber(3));
        System.out.println(phone.getPhoneNumber(2));
    }
}
```

My Driver:

```
    package aaronjonesprog1;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Aaron
 */
public class AJDissector
{

    private String phoneColon;
    private int areaCode, preCode, number, countryCode, emptyNum;   

    public AJDissector(String phoneNum)
    {
        this.phoneColon         = phoneNum;
        int index0      = phoneNum.indexOf(":");
        int index1      = phoneNum.indexOf(":", index0);
        int index2      = phoneNum.lastIndexOf(":");

        this.countryCode    = Integer.parseInt(phoneNum.substring(0, index0));
        this.areaCode       = Integer.parseInt(phoneNum.substring(index0, index1));
        this.preCode        = Integer.parseInt(phoneNum.substring(index1, index2));
        this.number         = Integer.parseInt(phoneNum.substring(index2));
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return this.phoneColon;
    }

    public int getPhoneNumber(int a)
    {
        switch (a) 
        {
            case 1:
                return this.number;
            case 2:
                return this.countryCode;
            case 3:
                return this.preCode;
            case 4:
                return this.number;
            default:
                return this.emptyNum;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I receive is:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at aaronjonesprog1.AJDissector.<init>(AJDissector.java:26)
    at aaronjonesprog1.AaronJonesProg1.main(AaronJonesProg1.java:18)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? I don't believe I am using the `parseInt` wrong. I looked at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html in an attempt to figure it out but I THINK my code is correct. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger and step through your code. That is the most valuable advice you can get.

Comment: I went to Debug, and it showed a green line in my code. Then I pressed F5 and it spit out the same error I have above...?

Comment: Just so it's said, phone numbers are not numbers.  Yeah, they consist of digits, but that doesn't make them numbers; they could as easily have been the letters A through J.  (In fact, companies *do* use letters in their "numbers".  Often.)  Ints generally suck at storing them...for reasons including the fact that even if you convert letters to digits, leading zeroes can be significant in a phone number.

Comment: Right; it would be better to control the entirety of the number as a String I would think however due to the assignment I have to turn them into int.

Comment: @Aaron you need to put a breakpoint in your code. Typically, this is done by clicking in the left margin of the code area on the line you want to halt on. Without a breakpoint, execution will not halt so "debug" will do the same thing as "run".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a another way to do this of your intrested. You can use the string.replace method to break it up and or to insert your : notation here is example from another program

```
 outputString = outputString.replaceAll(",",",\n" + " " );
 outputString = outputString.replaceAll("\\{","\\{\n" +" ");
 outputString = outputString.replaceAll(":",": ");
 outputString = outputString.replaceAll("}",",\n}");
 StringTokenizer output2 = new StringTokenizer(outputString,", ",true);
```

This set of replace string does some bizzare formating that to complicated to explaine for the topic of this post but study ythis and you will get the idea. To inderstand this refer to the java String api

Comment: Is StringTokenizer a function you created?

Comment: I used this and replaced my other stuff; it works now. Thanks so much!

Comment: String Tokenizer is another java class in the API, very usfull you should learn that also!

Comment: arron, im trying to build my reputation can you give my souition an up arrow. Thanks

Comment: I only have 14 reputation and require 15 to do that. I tried earlier to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `substring` method *begins* the sub-string at the specified index, inclusive. The values that you're getting from `indexOf` are the indices of a `:` character. There are problems with your usage of `substring` *and* `indexOf(char, index)`.

Print out - or inspect in the debugger - each index that you get, and your sub-strings before trying to parse them, and you'll see what's wrong.

For example, in your `AJDissector` constructor where you're getting the substrings, try:

```
System.out.println("substring 2 indexes: " + index0 + ", " + index1);
System.out.println("substring 2: " + phoneNum.substring(index0, index1));
```

For each index, look at the whole `String`, and - remembering that indices begin at `0` - do the work of `substring` in your head.

Comment: index0 is equal to 1
index1 is equal to 1
index2 is equal to 9

So I am using indexOf improperly it would appear. Thanks!

Comment: Dont forget to mark pb2q's answer as the solution as that will help other folks with the same issue.

Comment: Still working on my assignment. I haven't got the substring stuff to work yet; but I am looking at the other answer with the util scanner as an alternative. Ill mark as soon as I get this thing working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look a little further through the Java API, possibly at something like: `java.util.Scanner`.

From the javadocs:

> A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings
>   using regular expressions.
>
> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be
>   converted into values of different types using the various next
>   methods.

[java.util.Scanner API Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Scanner.html)